# x-momentum operator $p_x$ expressed as multiple of Translation operator

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

On this page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_%28quantum_mechanics%29

under  "The translation operator,"  they use Taylor expansion.
As part of that proof they state

$p_x = ih * dT(0)/da$

By T(0) they do not mean T evaluated at 0;  they mean the translation
operator that does nothing.

But what do they MEAN by $p_x = ih * dT(0)/da$?  Can't that be read
as  "the x momentum operator is a scalar multiple of the rate of
change in the translation operator, if upgraded by an infinitesimally
small amount da, to a  'bigger'  translation operator"?   What does
that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a little more sense if I think about it as:

Our goal is to create an operator that shifts the entire wave
function over by an amount  (translation).  We have an operator
that is essentially the derivative  (momentum operator).

Let's say we want to shift it over by an amount $\Delta x$.
A first approximation would be to create a function that
returns the value
$\psi(x_0) + (\Delta x * d\psi/dx (x_0))$ at every point $x_0$.

Then this is a very crude approximation of the original $\psi(x)$
shifted over by $\Delta x$.

How could we make the approximation better?  Well instead of only
using the first derivative once, what if we used the first
derivative to get us to $x$ + (some portion of $\Delta x$) say just
$1/10 *  \Delta x$.  Then we have a new
$\psi_1$ function which took care of  "10%"  of the total translation.

Then apply the system again:  Take the first derivative of $\psi_1$ again
at every point, and then use that to approximately bump every point
over by another $1/10 * \Delta x$.  That gives us $\psi_2$ which is shifted
over now by 20% of the total goal.  And what if we did this all the way to
$\psi_{10}$.

Well that would make a very good approximation for $\psi$ shifted over
by the full $\Delta x$, and the expression representing all that process would
be:

$(1 + (1/10 * \Delta x) * d\psi/dx)(1 + (1/10 * \Delta x) * d\psi/dx) .. (1 + (1/10 * \Delta x) * d\psi/dx)$, right?  Which if you expand it out with the
binomial theorem
gets you something that looks very much like the Taylor expansion of
e.  Hence if you did this to a finer and finer degree, you'd eventually
end up with $e^{(\Delta x) d/dx}$.
Which is basically what we write as the formula for the translation operator,
$e^{\Delta x (i/\hbar)\hat{p} }$.